# GET parameter passed through an .htaccess subdomain not read by php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

### Scenario

I've got the following code:

*test.php*

```
<?php
if(empty($_GET['lang'])){
    $user_language = explode("-",$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
    $language = $user_language[0];
    header('Location: http://'.$language.'.localhost'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
else{
    $lang = $_GET['lang'];
    $content = array("en"=>"This is a test.","it"=>"Questo è un test.");
    echo $content[$lang];
}
?>
```

*.htaccess*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^\.localhost$ 
RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,E=LANG:%1]
RewriteRule (.*) $1?lang=%{ENV:LANG} [QSA]
```

### What my code should do

If $_GET['lang'] is not defined, get user's language from headers sent from his browser and redirect them to the subdomain that corresponds to their language: the subdomain should coincide to $_GET['lang'].

### What isn't working

By visiting localhost/test.php, I get redirected to the right subdomain, but the redirect loops endlessly.
Plus, if I visit en.localhost/test.php and my language is Italian, I get redirected to it.localhost/test.php before the loop.

### My question

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^([a-z]{2}) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=LANG:%1]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)lang= [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:[^.]+\.)?(localhost)$
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{ENV:LANG}.%1/$1?lang=%{ENV:LANG} [QSA,L,R=302]
```

**Test.php**:

```
<?php
    $lang = $_GET['lang'];
    $content = array("en"=>"This is a test.","it"=>"Questo è un test.");
    echo $content[$lang];
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately this doesn't work: while when I visit localhost/test.php I get redirected only once to it.localhost/test.php, when I visit en.localhost/test.php the page is displayed in Italian anyway

Comment: See updated answer. Also see suggested `Test.php`, it shouldn't do any redirect since it is being handled in rewrite rules now.

Comment: Thanks again, this works if I visit localhost/test.php, but, if I go to en.localhost/test.php or to it.localhost/test.php I get "Undefined index: lang"